# Comparing multiple datalists and show different results

Tags: javascript, arrays, datalist

I am very new to coding, so I'm already sorry if this is a stupid question.
I want to compare four datalists which all contain a list of all countries. 
The user should pick a country in the first datalist.
If the user picks the same country in the second, third or fourth datalist, I want to show the country of the first datalist below.
If the selected countries of the second, third or fourth datalist does not match the country of the first datalist, I want to show the selected country of the fourth datalist below.

I hope you guys understood what I am trying to say.

I am very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

```js
var inputs1 = ['country1', 'country2', 'country3', 'country4'].map(c => document.getElementsByName(c)[0]),
  country1, country2, country3, country4;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs1.length; i++) {
  var el = inputs1[i];
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    compareLists(this.value);
  })
}

function compareLists() {
  var map = {};
  inputs1.forEach((i, idx) => {
    i.value && ((map[i.value]?.push(idx)) || (map[i.value] = [idx]));
  });
  // use an object map to collect duplicates
 
  // filter out only dupe lists > 1 in length
  map = Object.entries(map).filter(([, x]) => x.length > 1);
  console.log(map);

  // compare the list

  if (inputs1[0].value == inputs1[1].value || inputs1[0].value == inputs1[2].value || inputs1[0].value == inputs1[3].value){
   document.getElementById("ebene2").classList.add('showing');
  } else {
   document.getElementById("ebene3").classList.add('showing');
  }
}
```

```css
.fragen {display: none;}
.showing {display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="response3no" class="showing">
    <h3>In welchem Staat sind die folgenden Orte? </h3>

     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Beförderers: 
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country1" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
         <option value="Afghanistan"> 
        <option value="Ägypten"> 
        <option value="Albanien"> 
        <option value="Algerien"> 
        <option value="Andorra"> 
        <option value="Angola"> 
        <option value="Antigua und Barbuda"> 
        <option value="Äquatorialguinea"> 
        <option value="Argentinien"> 
        <option value="Armenien">
        <option value="Aserbaidschan">  
        <option value="Äthiopien"> 
        <option value="Australien">
        <option value="Bahamas">
        <option value="Bahrain">
        <option value="Bangladesch">
        <option value="Barbados">
        <option value="Belarus"> 
        <option value="Belgien">
        <option value="Belize">
        <option value="Benin">
        <option value="Bhutan">
        <option value="Bolivien">
        <option value="Bosnien und Herzegowina">
        <option value="Botsuana">
        <option value="Brasilien">
        <option value="Brunei Darussalam">
        <option value="Bulgarien">
        <option value="Burkina Faso">
        <option value="Burundi">
        <option value="Cabo Verde">
        <option value="Chile">
        <option value="China">
        <option value="Cookinseln">
        <option value="Costa Rica">
        <option value="Côte d'Ivoire">
        <option value="Dänemark">
        <option value="Deutschland">
        <option value="Dominica">
        <option value="Dominikanische Republik">
        <option value="Dschibuti">
        <option value="Ecuador">
        <option value="El Salvador">
        <option value=Eritrea>
        <option value="Estland">
        <option value="Eswatini">
        <option value="Fidschi">
        <option value="Finnland">
        <option value="Frankreich">
        <option value="Gabun">
        <option value="Gambia">
        <option value="Georgien">
        <option value="Ghana">
        <option value="Grenada">
        <option value="Griechenland">
        <option value="Großbritannien">
        <option value="Guatemala">
        <option value="Guinea">
        <option value="Guinea-Bissau">
        <option value="Guyana">
        <option value="Haiti">
        <option value="Honduras">
        <option value="Indien">
        <option value="Indonesien">
        <option value="Irak">
        <option value="Iran">
        <option value="Irland">
        <option value="Island">
        <option value="Israel">
        <option value="Italien">
        <option value="Jamaika">
        <option value="Japan">
        <option value="Jemen">
        <option value="Jordanien">
        <option value="Kambodscha">
        <option value="Kamerun">
        <option value="Kanada">
        <option value="Kasachstan">
        <option value="Katar">
        <option value="Kenia">
        <option value="Kirgistan">
        <option value="Kiribati">
        <option value="Kolumbien">
        <option value="Komoren">
        <option value="Kongo">
        <option value="Kongo, Demokratische Republik">
        <option value="Korea, Demokratische Volksrepublik">
        <option value="Korea, Republik">
        <option value="Kosovo">
        <option value="Kroatien">
        <option value="Kuba">
        <option value="Kuwait">
        <option value="Laos">
        <option value="Lesotho">
        <option value="Lettland">
        <option value="Libanon">
        <option value="Liberia">
        <option value="Libyen">
        <option value="Liechtenstein">
        <option value="Litauen">
        <option value="Luxemburg">
        <option value="Madagaskar">
        <option value="Malawi">
        <option value="Malaysia">
        <option value="Malediven">
        <option value="Mali">
        <option value="Malta">
        <option value="Marokko">
        <option value="Marshallinseln">
        <option value="Mauretanien">
        <option value="Mauritius">
        <option value="Mexiko">
        <option value="Mikronesien">
        <option value="Moldau">
        <option value="Monaco">
        <option value="Mongolei">
        <option value="Montenegro">
        <option value="Mosambik">
        <option value="Myanmar">
        <option value="Namibia">
        <option value="Nauru">
        <option value="Nepal">
        <option value="Neuseeland">
        <option value="Nicaragua">
        <option value="Niederlande">
        <option value="Niger">
        <option value="Nigeria">
        <option value="Nordmazedonien">
        <option value="Norwegen">
        <option value="Oman">
        <option value="Österreich">
        <option value="Pakistan">
        <option value="Palau">
        <option value="Panama">
        <option value="Papua-Neuguinea">
        <option value="Paraguay">
        <option value="Peru">
        <option value="Philippinen">
        <option value="Polen">
        <option value="Portugal">
        <option value="Ruanda">
        <option value="Rumänien">
        <option value="Russische Föderation">
        <option value="Salomonen">
        <option value="Sambia">
        <option value="Samoa">
        <option value="San Marino">
        <option value="São Tomé und Príncipe">
        <option value="Saudi-Arabien">
        <option value="Schweden">
        <option value="Schweiz">
        <option value="Senegal">
        <option value="Serbien">
        <option value="Seychellen">
        <option value="Sierra Leone">
        <option value="Simbabwe">
        <option value="Singapur">
        <option value="Slowakei">
        <option value="Slowenien">
        <option value="Somalia">
        <option value="Spanien">
        <option value="Sri Lanka">
        <option value="St. Kitts und Nevis">
        <option value="St Lucia">
        <option value="St. Vincent und die Grenadinen">
        <option value="Südafrika">
        <option value="Sudan">
        <option value="Südsudan">
        <option value="Suriname">
        <option value="Syrien">
        <option value="Tadschikistan">
        <option value="Taiwan">
        <option value="Tansania">
        <option value="Thailand">
        <option value="Timor-Leste">
        <option value="Togo">
        <option value="Tonga">
        <option value="Trinidad und Tobago">
        <option value="Tschad">
        <option value="Tschechische Republik">
        <option value="Tunesien">
        <option value="Türkei">
        <option value="Turkmenistan">
        <option value="Tuvalu">
        <option value="Uganda">
        <option value="Ukraine">
        <option value="Ungarn">
        <option value="Uruguay">
        <option value="Usbekistan">
        <option value="Vanuatu">
        <option value="Vatikanstadt">
        <option value="Venezuela">
        <option value="Vereinige Arabische Emirate">
        <option value="Vereinigte Staaten">
        <option value="Vietnam">
        <option value="Zentralafrikanische Republik">
        <option value="Zypern">
      </datalist>
  </form>
        <br>
     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Absenders 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country2" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Übernahmeort der Güter 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country3"list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Ablieferungsort der Güter
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country4" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
</div>

<div id="ebene2" class="fragen">
    <span id="firstcountry"></span>
</div>

<div id="ebene3" class="fragen">
    <span id="lastcountry"></span>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the JavaScript here from your example. The HTML and CSS are unchanged.

You'd have to take conditions other than logging to the console in each of those outcomes.

```js
const inputNames = [1,2,3,4].map(n => `country${n}`);
const inputElem = inputNames.map(c => document.getElementsByName(c)[0]);

inputElem.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
});

function handleChange() {
  const first = inputElem[0];
  const last = inputElem[inputElem.length -1];
  const middle = inputElem.filter(el => el !== first && el !== last);
  const middleValues = middle.map(el => el.value);

  if (first.value && middleValues.includes(first.value)) {
    console.log(`Show first country: ${first.value}`);
  } else if (last.value) {
    console.log(`Show last country: ${last.value}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No conditions met...`);
  }
}
```

```css
.fragen {display: none;}
.showing {display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="response3no" class="showing">
    <h3>In welchem Staat sind die folgenden Orte? </h3>

     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Beförderers: 
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country1" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
         <option value="Afghanistan"> 
        <option value="Ägypten"> 
        <option value="Albanien"> 
        <option value="Algerien"> 
        <option value="Andorra"> 
        <option value="Angola"> 
        <option value="Antigua und Barbuda"> 
        <option value="Äquatorialguinea"> 
        <option value="Argentinien"> 
        <option value="Armenien">
        <option value="Aserbaidschan">  
        <option value="Äthiopien"> 
        <option value="Australien">
        <option value="Bahamas">
        <option value="Bahrain">
        <option value="Bangladesch">
        <option value="Barbados">
        <option value="Belarus"> 
        <option value="Belgien">
        <option value="Belize">
        <option value="Benin">
        <option value="Bhutan">
        <option value="Bolivien">
        <option value="Bosnien und Herzegowina">
        <option value="Botsuana">
        <option value="Brasilien">
        <option value="Brunei Darussalam">
        <option value="Bulgarien">
        <option value="Burkina Faso">
        <option value="Burundi">
        <option value="Cabo Verde">
        <option value="Chile">
        <option value="China">
        <option value="Cookinseln">
        <option value="Costa Rica">
        <option value="Côte d'Ivoire">
        <option value="Dänemark">
        <option value="Deutschland">
        <option value="Dominica">
        <option value="Dominikanische Republik">
        <option value="Dschibuti">
        <option value="Ecuador">
        <option value="El Salvador">
        <option value=Eritrea>
        <option value="Estland">
        <option value="Eswatini">
        <option value="Fidschi">
        <option value="Finnland">
        <option value="Frankreich">
        <option value="Gabun">
        <option value="Gambia">
        <option value="Georgien">
        <option value="Ghana">
        <option value="Grenada">
        <option value="Griechenland">
        <option value="Großbritannien">
        <option value="Guatemala">
        <option value="Guinea">
        <option value="Guinea-Bissau">
        <option value="Guyana">
        <option value="Haiti">
        <option value="Honduras">
        <option value="Indien">
        <option value="Indonesien">
        <option value="Irak">
        <option value="Iran">
        <option value="Irland">
        <option value="Island">
        <option value="Israel">
        <option value="Italien">
        <option value="Jamaika">
        <option value="Japan">
        <option value="Jemen">
        <option value="Jordanien">
        <option value="Kambodscha">
        <option value="Kamerun">
        <option value="Kanada">
        <option value="Kasachstan">
        <option value="Katar">
        <option value="Kenia">
        <option value="Kirgistan">
        <option value="Kiribati">
        <option value="Kolumbien">
        <option value="Komoren">
        <option value="Kongo">
        <option value="Kongo, Demokratische Republik">
        <option value="Korea, Demokratische Volksrepublik">
        <option value="Korea, Republik">
        <option value="Kosovo">
        <option value="Kroatien">
        <option value="Kuba">
        <option value="Kuwait">
        <option value="Laos">
        <option value="Lesotho">
        <option value="Lettland">
        <option value="Libanon">
        <option value="Liberia">
        <option value="Libyen">
        <option value="Liechtenstein">
        <option value="Litauen">
        <option value="Luxemburg">
        <option value="Madagaskar">
        <option value="Malawi">
        <option value="Malaysia">
        <option value="Malediven">
        <option value="Mali">
        <option value="Malta">
        <option value="Marokko">
        <option value="Marshallinseln">
        <option value="Mauretanien">
        <option value="Mauritius">
        <option value="Mexiko">
        <option value="Mikronesien">
        <option value="Moldau">
        <option value="Monaco">
        <option value="Mongolei">
        <option value="Montenegro">
        <option value="Mosambik">
        <option value="Myanmar">
        <option value="Namibia">
        <option value="Nauru">
        <option value="Nepal">
        <option value="Neuseeland">
        <option value="Nicaragua">
        <option value="Niederlande">
        <option value="Niger">
        <option value="Nigeria">
        <option value="Nordmazedonien">
        <option value="Norwegen">
        <option value="Oman">
        <option value="Österreich">
        <option value="Pakistan">
        <option value="Palau">
        <option value="Panama">
        <option value="Papua-Neuguinea">
        <option value="Paraguay">
        <option value="Peru">
        <option value="Philippinen">
        <option value="Polen">
        <option value="Portugal">
        <option value="Ruanda">
        <option value="Rumänien">
        <option value="Russische Föderation">
        <option value="Salomonen">
        <option value="Sambia">
        <option value="Samoa">
        <option value="San Marino">
        <option value="São Tomé und Príncipe">
        <option value="Saudi-Arabien">
        <option value="Schweden">
        <option value="Schweiz">
        <option value="Senegal">
        <option value="Serbien">
        <option value="Seychellen">
        <option value="Sierra Leone">
        <option value="Simbabwe">
        <option value="Singapur">
        <option value="Slowakei">
        <option value="Slowenien">
        <option value="Somalia">
        <option value="Spanien">
        <option value="Sri Lanka">
        <option value="St. Kitts und Nevis">
        <option value="St Lucia">
        <option value="St. Vincent und die Grenadinen">
        <option value="Südafrika">
        <option value="Sudan">
        <option value="Südsudan">
        <option value="Suriname">
        <option value="Syrien">
        <option value="Tadschikistan">
        <option value="Taiwan">
        <option value="Tansania">
        <option value="Thailand">
        <option value="Timor-Leste">
        <option value="Togo">
        <option value="Tonga">
        <option value="Trinidad und Tobago">
        <option value="Tschad">
        <option value="Tschechische Republik">
        <option value="Tunesien">
        <option value="Türkei">
        <option value="Turkmenistan">
        <option value="Tuvalu">
        <option value="Uganda">
        <option value="Ukraine">
        <option value="Ungarn">
        <option value="Uruguay">
        <option value="Usbekistan">
        <option value="Vanuatu">
        <option value="Vatikanstadt">
        <option value="Venezuela">
        <option value="Vereinige Arabische Emirate">
        <option value="Vereinigte Staaten">
        <option value="Vietnam">
        <option value="Zentralafrikanische Republik">
        <option value="Zypern">
      </datalist>
  </form>
        <br>
     Sitz / gewöhnlicher Aufenthalt des Absenders 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country2" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Übernahmeort der Güter 
    <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country3" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
     Ablieferungsort der Güter
     <form>
      <input type="search" name ="country4" list="country">
      <datalist id="country">
        
      
      </datalist>
    </form>
        <br>
</div>

<div id="ebene2" class="fragen">
    <span id="firstcountry"></span>
</div>

<div id="ebene3" class="fragen">
    <span id="lastcountry"></span>
   
</div>
```